# What is a good high-quality alternative for the Bell MT font?

Tags: font-recommendation

I'm trying to create a logo in Photoshop using Bell MT font, but I'm finding that the edges are too sharp, making it look rather low in quality. Any suggestions for higher quality fonts that are similar in style?

Below is a sample of the font currently being used:

[image: example]

Comment: Hi Jessica, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. Do you have a picture of the font? Makes it easier to answer your question if you don't have it installed. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help center](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help) or ping one of us in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/the-ink-spot) once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 2):

At that small size, Bell MT looks rather like a [Caslon](http://www.myfonts.com/search/caslon/fonts/).

Most versions of Caslon's iconic font have a serif on the lower arm of the C, but there are a few cuts which don't and which might suit. From MyFonts.com, in no particular order...

- [LTC Caslon](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/lanston/ltc-caslon/)

  [image: LTC Caslon]
- [Caslon SB](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/efscangraphic/caslon-sb/)

  [image: Caslon SB]
- [Adobe Caslon Pro](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/adobe/caslon/)

  [image: Adobe Caslon Pro]
- [Bitstream Caslon Old Face](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/bitstream/caslon-old-face/)

  [image: Bitstream Caslon Old Face]
- [Williams Caslon Text](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/fontbureau/williams-caslon-text/)

  [image: Williams Caslon Text]
- [Berthold Caslon Book](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/berthold/caslon-book-be/)

  [image: Berthold Caslon Book]

Comment: Kudos, because this is very close - the main difference I see is the top of the "A", but this is entirely acceptable. I downloaded the Adobe Pro Caslon and I don't see a noticeable difference in quality, though.

Answer (score 0):

You may be interested in 'Cardo Regular', which is a free font here: http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/Cardo.

I wouldn't usually stray away from the apple recommended list, but Andrew Leach has covered most of the recognisable ones above.